# Woocommerce Category Heirarchy

Tags: wordpress, loops, woocommerce

How to show category hierarchy in woocommerce

What i want is something like this

given with this slug
**domain.com/category/balloons/helium-baloons**
the hierarchy would be:

- Baloons

  - Helium Baloons
- Decor
- Weddings

To simplified the idea it should be something like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use **wp_list_categories** function with arguments

```
wp_list_categories(
    array(
        'taxonomy'=>product_cat'
    )
);
```

Comment: actually i already had a loop but it show all the subcategories. i  want to achieve is like it only show the subcategories when your on the current children categories

Answer (score 0):

use the below code to achive this functionality

```
$myterms = get_terms( 'category', array( 'parent' => 0 ) );
$current_term = get_queried_object();
echo '<ul>';
foreach($myterms as $term){ 
    echo '<li> <a href="'.get_term_link($term->term_id).'">'.$term->name.'</a>';
    if($term->term_id == $current_term->parent){
        $child_terms = get_terms( 'category', array('child_of'=>$term->term_id) );
        if($child_terms){
            echo '<ul>';
                foreach($child_terms as $child_term){
                    echo '<li> <a href="'.get_term_link($child_term->term_id).'">'.$child_term->name.'</a>';
                }
            echo '</ul>';

        }
    }
    echo '</li>';   
}
echo '</ul>';
```

also if you have big child heirarchi you can make this code recursive.